# Prove $e^\alpha = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{\alpha}{n})^n$ from first principles.

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Prove $$e^\alpha = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{\alpha}{n})^n$$

from first principles.

I know the proof for $e^1$, so in particular how could a generic formula for that limit (either with squeeze theorem, or just basic manipulation of your choice) lead to the general formula above?

Feel free to use whatever proof you want, as long as it is generally understandable for people with only a beginning/intermediate understanding of calculus.

Comment: Is l'Hopital's rule allowed?

Comment: What is your definition of $e$ ?

Comment: Please give your **definition** of $e$ and $e^\alpha$. If one wants to prove something from the first principle, one must know what is the principle first!

Comment: The $n$ in your question is supposed to be a positive integer. Also your result for $\alpha=1$ is one of the popular definitions of $e$. Under these suppositions you can prove using a little bit of algebra that the result holds for all rational $\alpha$. The result is true for irrational as well as complex $\alpha$ also, but this is not possible to handle just via algebraic manipulation and it also depends on the definition of symbol $e^{\alpha} $ in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the proof
$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n = e$

And don't need to prove this again.

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac an)^n$

let $n = am$

$\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} (1+\frac 1m)^{am} =\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} ((1+\frac 1m)^{m})^a$

Comment: What if $a\le 0$?  And since $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $m=n/a$ need not be an integer.  This proof is limited to rational $a$.